# How can I get a CSS class selector to override the input[readonly] selector?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have the following CSS to insure that all readonly textboxes have the background color set to grey...

```
input[readonly]
{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

But now I want to override that style for a TextBox with CssClass="WarningText" but the following does not work...

```
.WarningText
{
    background-color: #ffff99;
}
```

How can I get the .WarningText style to override the default input[readonly] style?

Comment: `input[readonly].WarningText`  doesn't work?

Comment: try adding a !importat tag like this 'background-color: #ffff99 !important;'

Comment: @Paulie_D, Yes that does work!  I tried that but had a space before the .WarningText - which was something completely unintended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain the attribute and class selector(s) like so:

```css
input[readonly] {
  background-color: grey;
}

input[readonly].WarningText {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="WarningText" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use valid CSS Selectors so like @paulie_d said `input[readonly].WarningText` should do what you are expecting it to do. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
input[readonly="readonly"].WarningText
{
    background-color: #ffff99;
}
```